# Calculate the coordinates for the point on the surface of an igloo where a solar panel will be attached

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

So this question came up in past exams and it's quite beefy. I'll continue below.

An igloo has a base that lies in the x-y plane and the surface is given by the function

$z = f(x, y) = 4-\frac{1}{5}x^2-\frac{6}{25}y^2+\frac{1}{25}xy$

A solar panel must be attached to this igloo and maximum efficiency will be attained when the solar panel is directed true north at a tilt angle of $48.7$ degrees from the *vertical* axis.

This would mean the solar panel would have a normal vector of;

$n=(18, 22, 25)$

Calculate the coordinates for the point on the surface of the igloo where the solar panel will be attached.

This *sounds* like a coordinate question where I can use or manipulate the vector equation of a plane to find the point where the solar panel will be attached. Something of this form comes to mind.

$n * (r-r_{0}) = 0$

But I'm not really sure how to progress from here.

Thanks in advance, I'm ready here to listen and try to make progress on this or see how it's answered :)

Comment: Hint 1: tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at some unknown point $(a,b)$. You seek the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$.

Comment: Hint 2: Define $F$ by $F(x,y,z) = z - f(x,y)$. The graph of $f$ is the level surface $F(x,y,z) = 0$. Recall: $\nabla F(a,b,c)$ is normal to the tangent plane I mentioned above; so if $\mathbf{n} = \langle 18, 22, 25 \rangle$ is a normal vector for the solar panel (tangent plane), then $\nabla F(a,b,c) \parallel \mathbf{n}$.